# if error, do this and return, else continue execution in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

There are lots of repetitions in my code like this block:

```
if err:
    print('Could not parse text!')
    print('Error code={}'.format(err.code))
    print('Error message={}'.format(err.message))
    return err.code
```

I want to make it look nicer, maybe in just one line of code.

So I want to order the compiler to do this in one line:

**if there is an error, print necessary information and return error code, otherwise continue execution.**

Something like this:

```
def error_output(err, text):
    print(text)
    print('Error code={}'.format(err.code))
    print('Error message={}'.format(err.message))
    return err.code

return_if(err, error_output, 'Parse error')
```

Tried this:

```
return error_output(err,'parse error') if err else continue
```

But of course it's not possible to use `continue` like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
if err: return error_output(err, 'parse error') 
# more code here
```

Comment: That's acceptable to some measures, although it's quite small code, my intent is to know if there is a way to block return with a condition.

Comment: `return` is a statement. You cannot turn it into an expression. It has to return.

Comment: You *could* make a `raise_if` function, where it raises a given exception to be caught even higher up. Exceptions are usually the correct way to handle error conditions in Python, so if you're stuck with some error code based API, converting the error codes to exceptions would hide the ugliness of error code returns from the rest of your code.

Comment: @RamazanPolat, you asked for a way to do it on one line (presumably to minimise vertical code space requirements, which I *do* understand) - this answer provides exactly that.

Comment: @MikeMüller "It has to return" is the answer I was looking.